# Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010, concurrency limitations

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a small site (asp.net) for which i created a few reports using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010.
They are very basic reports and the user only has the option of exporting to pdf (not even to view it in browser before exporting).

The site is hosted in IIS.

For the past few days, the time taken to open a report is varying greatly, which i believe could be due to multiple users opening the report simultaneously.

Reading up some articles on the web, i found out that there are some concurrency limitations with Crystal Reports, but haven't been able to find out the exact details.

So could someone tell me what exactly are the limitations?
How can i overcome these limitations (purchase license?)

Comment: are you closing & disposing properly?

Comment: the report is disposed once exported as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

what's your datasource on your crystal report? is ir thru stored procedure, tables/command?

if you're using SP as datasource can you show me your SP?

if you're using tables/command as datasource then the issue would be connectivity and resources available in the Server.

Comment: Datasource is a stored procedure. The performance of the sproc is consistent. Only the report takes a varying time to open, and i suspect it has something to do with concurrency.